# Problems reading CSV that uses quotations for fields that contain a comma

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

My CSV file headers are set up like this:

```
COMPANY NAME,Email,Job Title,COMPANY TYPE,CITY,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME
```

And I've got some code to read the records from the file:

```
var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
if (ofd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
_importFile = ofd.FileName;
Engine = new CsvEngine("record", ',', _importFile);
Records = Engine.ReadFile(_importFile);
```

This code has worked fine for me with other csv files I've used, but when I use it with my current file, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'FileHelpers.BadUsageException' occurred in FileHelpers.dll
>
> Additional information: Line: 180 Column: 149. Delimiter ',' found after the last field 'LASTNAME' (the file is wrong or you need to add a field to the record class)

This is the record in question, at line 180:

```
"Bbc Worldwide Labs, Bounce Republic Ltd",hidden@hidden.com,"Broadcaster, Voice Over & Founder Of Passion Pods",Broadcast Media,London,Emily,Chiswell
```

This record matches the field headers given. So what's the problem?

The only thing I can imagine causing this problem is the commas given within the other fields. But they're encapsulated with quotations, so this shouldn't be an issue, right?

**EDIT**

I am using the FileHelpers library to parse the CSV: http://www.filehelpers.net/

Comment: This CsvEngine - you made it yourself or it is some 3rd party?

Comment: The most likely answer is that `CsvEngine` doesn't understand quoted fields. You may want to pick one of many other CSV readers that do handle them properly.

Comment: I am using FileHelpers: http://www.filehelpers.net/

Comment: Downvoted for what? Is my question not clear enough?

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne, You are using a third party library that claims to be able to read csv yet cannot deal with quoted text that contains the delimiter, which is part of the spec. I suggest changing to a library that can handler such.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of [CsvEngine](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/M_FileHelpers_CsvEngine__ctor_2.htm),

The constructor takes only a single delimiter character which is `','`.

Since you have commas in the other fields, they are also considered as delimiters and the line would be split for all the `','` characters.

So,

```
"Bbc Worldwide Labs, Bounce Republic Ltd",hidden@hidden.com,"Broadcaster, Voice Over & Founder Of Passion Pods",Broadcast Media,London,Emily,Chiswell
```

would be split into following:

1. "Bbc Worldwide Labs
2. Bounce Republic Ltd"
3. hidden@hidden.com
4. "Broadcaster
5. Voice Over & Founder Of Passion Pods"
6. Broadcast Media
7. London
8. Emily
9. Chiswell

Which does not match with your 7 fields as per your header. So, you are getting

> Delimiter ',' found after the last field 'LASTNAME'

because there is ',' after LASTNAME. So it is considering London as LASTNAME

Comment: Okay, but this is not a solution to my problem.

Comment: The .NET TextFieldParser (Part of .NET Framework) should be able to handle this.

Comment: Using `','` is not an option then. Since you are using a 3rd party library, either change your delimiter character, or remove the commas in the other fields

Answer (score 0):

Using the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO Assembly you should be able to do something like this:

```
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("yourfile"))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                //Process row
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                foreach (string field in fields)
                {
                    //TODO: Process field
                }
            }
        }
```

Take care of your header lines by skipping the header line(s)

Answer (score 0):

Using Cinchoo ETL (an open source library at GitHub), you can load your CSV file

```
COMPANY NAME, Email, Job Title,COMPANY TYPE, CITY, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
"Bbc Worldwide Labs, Bounce Republic Ltd",hidden @hidden.com,"Broadcaster, Voice Over & Founder Of Passion Pods", Broadcast Media, London, Emily, Chiswell
```

Parsing the above file can be done as below

```
foreach (dynamic rec in new ChoCSVReader("EmpQuote.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
{
    Console.WriteLine(rec.COMPANY_NAME);
    Console.WriteLine(rec.COMPANY_TYPE);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have found a bug in FileHelpers.

Try this code:

```
var co = new FileHelpers.Options.CsvOptions("Output", ',', 7);
co.HeaderLines = 0;
var ce = new FileHelpers.CsvEngine(co);
var output = ce.ReadString(@"Bbc Worldwide Labs Bounce Republic Ltd,hidden@hidden.com,""Broadcaster, Voice Over & Founder Of Passion Pods"",Broadcast Media,London,Emily,Chiswell
```

""Bbc Worldwide Labs, Bounce Republic Ltd"",hidden@hidden.com,""Broadcaster, Voice Over & Founder Of Passion Pods"",Broadcast Media,London,EmilyChiswell")

That gives:

[image: output]

As you can see the second field with the `','` works just fine. It appears that the error is in parsing the first field if it has a comma.

---

Here's how to get it to work.

Define an import class:

```
[FileHelpers.DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Orders
{
    [FileHelpers.FieldQuoted]
    public string CompanyName;
    public string Email;
    [FileHelpers.FieldQuoted]
    public string JobTitle;
    public string CompanyType;
    public string City;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName; 
}
```

Now this code works:

```
    var ce = new FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine<Orders>();

    var output = ce.ReadString(@"Bbc Worldwide Labs Bounce Republic Ltd,hidden@hidden.com,""Broadcaster, Voice Over & Founder Of Passion Pods"",Broadcast Media,London,Emily,Chiswell
""Bbc Worldwide Labs, Bounce Republic Ltd"",hidden@hidden.com,""Broadcaster, Voice Over & Founder Of Passion Pods"",Broadcast Media,London,Emily,Chiswell");
```

It gives:

[image: output fixed]

Comment: That's great and all, but I can't define classes for the csv because the field names are always changing. It's different csv files every time.